# CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my database structure.
cities -> landmarks -> attractions(each one is a collection)

**Query**
List all attractions under a particular city.

**Solution**

Save city_id in each attraction document

Use a collection group query and filter based on city_id to get attractions of a particular city.

**My Question**

Instead of saving city_id in each attraction document, can I just specify the document to the collectionGroupQuery which now only searches in subcollections under this particular document.

In the above example, I specify the city document's full path and i should be able to list all attractions without filtering based on city_id.

Answer (score 24):

This should work using [`FieldPath.documentId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#documentid).

Each document has a hidden `__name__` field in its data and this is the target of `FieldPath.documentId()`.

For a normal collection query, `FieldPath.documentId()` would just be the document's ID. However, for a collection group query, this value is the document's path.

We should be able to use this to find all matching document paths that start with the given city's document path like so:

```js
const cityRef = firebase.firestore().doc('cities/cityId');

firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('attractions')
  .orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
  .startAt(cityRef.path + "/"),
  .endAt(cityRef.path + "/\uf8ff")
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    console.log("Found " + querySnapshot.size + " docs");
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => console.log("> " + doc.ref.path))
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to execute query", err);
  })
```

---

**Edit:** While the above code would function [if the SDK allowed it](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/2e6d95a0851304a9b7c069f55e5c8fb817a5e3cc/packages/firestore/src/lite/query.ts#L697-L704), it currently throws an error about having an odd number of segments because of the extra `/`.

For now, as long as all your city IDs are the same length (as they would be if using the default `docRef.add()`), the below code would function:

```js
const cityRef = firebase.firestore().doc('cities/cityId');

firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('attractions')
  .orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
  .startAt(cityRef.path),
  .endAt(cityRef.path + "\uf8ff")
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    console.log("Found " + querySnapshot.size + " docs");
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => console.log("> " + doc.ref.path))
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to execute query", err);
  })
```

Where the above block fails is if the document ID have different lengths. Let's say you only wanted documents under `"/cities/New York"`, if another city called `"New Yorkshire"` was also in the cities collection, it would have it's results included too.

Comment: Interesting approach! Do you have a source for "for a collection group query, this value is the document's path", as I don't think I've ever read that before?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen From the way I understood it, it's a matter of uniqueness. In a single collection, only one document may have a given ID but across multiple collections, many docs may share an ID, so it uses their path for uniqueness. The [source of the JS SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/2e6d95a0851304a9b7c069f55e5c8fb817a5e3cc/packages/firestore/src/lite/query.ts#L673-L716) has some explicit error handling for handling any bad inputs. [@doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126) referenced this behaviour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56189687/3068190).

Comment: In that link Doug suggests explicitly storing the document ID inside the document itself. I don't think I've ever seen a prefix condition on the document ID, let alone on the path that it may contain (I don't think I've ever seen that statement either). I'm trying to set up a repro for this now, as (if this is indeed possible, even if complex) it would invalidate quite some existing answers.

Comment: @FrankvanPufflen when you say "invalidate quite some existing answers", do you mean that this is a bug or something that is unintentionally useful? Also I wasn't referring to the answer Doug gave, but his comment regarding the path being returned when used on Collection Group queries.

Comment: Whenever folks have asked: can I query collections under a certain path, the answer I've given (and hence others have given after that) has been "this is currently not possible with Firestore". If your answer works, those answers would be incorrect.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Maybe I should have been more vocal about it when I found out about this quirk months ago while working on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/aea3bc9481bbab0a7fbc72069940e527). In my sandbox this approach worked fine but I haven't tried it at scale nor tested if it causes hotspotting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233969/discussion-between-frank-van-puffelen-and-samthecodingman).

Comment: Just marked as "recommended by Google Cloud". Really good answer!

Comment: Very nice discovery. @FrankvanPuffelen based on your discussion in the break out room, it sounds like this is a supported feature. Any plans to add it to Firestore's documentation?

Comment: The chatroom may only be readable to those who participated in it. As there's nothing sensitive in there, I've copied the thread across to [pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/zxhZJhYR).

Comment: As said in the chat, this is a valid use of the way the `documentID` field is built for collection group queries, and there are no plans to break it. In fact, I'm relying on it in the code for a talk later this month, and wished I could upvote this answer again.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If it gets recorded I'd love a link to the talk sent to me on Twitter or the Firebase Slack. If it's relevant here, I can also edit it into the answer

Comment: I just implemented it with angular firebase and works great but I´m new to firebase and was not able to grasp the mechanics that we take advantage of here. Can someone explain in a bit more detail how this works?

Comment: @MaxTuzenko It's a flow on from how you would do ["start with X"](https://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs?t=301) queries in the Realtime Database. I use the same "start with X" approach to "find all documents that have a path that starts with X". To cut off any results that don't start with X, but are sorted after it, I add an `endAt` filter to the query to make sure it returns only paths that start with X and omit the other results. `\uf8ff` is a character with a very high Unicode codepoint, which grabs basically anything useful with a lower code point - similar to `1 <= x <= 1.9999999`.

Comment: @IT-Guy007 Because of how this query works, you'd need to make a query for each `cityRef`. So convert the code here into a function that accepts the reference and the collection name, and then call it like so: `Promise.allSettled(cityRefArr.map((cityRef) => getDocs(nestedCollectionGroupQuery(cityRef, 'attractions'))))` (`cityRef.firestore` can be used to pull out the appropriate `Firestore` instance to use with the `collectionGroup` call).