# Firestore Collection Group Queries for showing Items based on Category Names

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a Multiple Restaurant Online Ordering Android app with Admin App and Restaurant App. In the User app, a Category section is there, where users can view a list of items based on the category name.

I am using Firestore for saving and retrieving data. In the admin app, I can add a restaurant and its menu items. I have set the database like the below structure.

```
Restaurant
     |
     Restaurant Id (in this case I have used restaurant username for id)
       |(1st branch)                              |(2nd branch)
       MenuItems (SubCollection)     All other Properties of Restaurants
        |
        MenuId (Auto Generated Id)
          | 
          All Menu Properties
```

See the below screenshots for a better understanding

[1st Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPftk.png)
[2nd Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxHjA.png)

As we can add Subcollections under a document,  I have done so for adding the menu items and did not think of getting the categories later based on the category item name.

Below is my APP Screenshot.

[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0RB7.jpg)

Now the problem arises when I am trying to fetch the items. I have searched many things regarding this and eventually found **Firestore Group Queries**. I have also implemented the same in the app but did not get the result. All the classes are below.

**FoodsFromCategories.java** (Activity Class)

```
public class FoodsFromCategories extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView itemrecycler;
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    CollectionReference collectionReference;
    String catnameref;
    List<String> list;
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MenuModel> menuModelFirestoreRecyclerOptions;
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<MenuModel, FoodsFromCatAdapter> adapterFirestoreRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foods_from_categories);
        catnameref = getIntent().getStringExtra("catName");
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarcat);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Delicious " + catnameref);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        itemrecycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewcatpage);
        itemrecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(FoodsFromCategories.this));

        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurants");
       list = new ArrayList<>();

       Query query = collectionReference.orderBy("MenuItems").whereEqualTo("itemCat", catnameref);

       menuModelFirestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<MenuModel>().setQuery(query, MenuModel.class).build();
       adapterFirestoreRecyclerAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<MenuModel, FoodsFromCatAdapter>(menuModelFirestoreRecyclerOptions) {
           @Override
           protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodsFromCatAdapter holder, int position, @NonNull MenuModel model) {
               holder.ifromRescat.setText(model.getResname());

           }

           @NonNull
           @Override
           public FoodsFromCatAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
               View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_product_item_from_cats, parent, false);
               return  new FoodsFromCatAdapter(view);
           }
       };
       adapterFirestoreRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
       itemrecycler.setAdapter(adapterFirestoreRecyclerAdapter);

    }
}
```

**MenuModel.java** (Model Class)

```
public class MenuModel {
    String finalprice, itemcat, itemlargesizename, itemname, itemsmallsizename, largesizeprice, originalprice, productimage, resid, smallsizeprice, status, menuid, resname;

    public MenuModel() {
    }

    public MenuModel(String finalprice, String itemcat, String itemlargesizename, String itemname, String itemsmallsizename, String largesizeprice, String originalprice, String productimage, String resid, String smallsizeprice, String status, String menuid, String resname) {
        this.finalprice = finalprice;
        this.itemcat = itemcat;
        this.itemlargesizename = itemlargesizename;
        this.itemname = itemname;
        this.itemsmallsizename = itemsmallsizename;
        this.largesizeprice = largesizeprice;
        this.originalprice = originalprice;
        this.productimage = productimage;
        this.resid = resid;
        this.smallsizeprice = smallsizeprice;
        this.status = status;
        this.menuid = menuid;
        this.resname = resname;
    }

    public String getResname() {
        return resname;
    }

    public void setResname(String resnamecat) {
        this.resname = resnamecat;
    }

    public String getMenuid() {
        return menuid;
    }

    public void setMenuid(String menuid) {
        this.menuid = menuid;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getFinalprice() {
        return finalprice;
    }

    public void setFinalprice(String finalprice) {
        this.finalprice = finalprice;
    }

    public String getItemcat() {
        return itemcat;
    }

    public void setItemcat(String itemcat) {
        this.itemcat = itemcat;
    }

    public String getItemlargesizename() {
        return itemlargesizename;
    }

    public void setItemlargesizename(String itemlargesizename) {
        this.itemlargesizename = itemlargesizename;
    }

    public String getItemname() {
        return itemname;
    }

    public void setItemname(String itemname) {
        this.itemname = itemname;
    }

    public String getItemsmallsizename() {
        return itemsmallsizename;
    }

    public void setItemsmallsizename(String itemsmallsizename) {
        this.itemsmallsizename = itemsmallsizename;
    }

    public String getLargesizeprice() {
        return largesizeprice;
    }

    public void setLargesizeprice(String largesizeprice) {
        this.largesizeprice = largesizeprice;
    }

    public String getOriginalprice() {
        return originalprice;
    }

    public void setOriginalprice(String originalprice) {
        this.originalprice = originalprice;
    }

    public String getProductimage() {
        return productimage;
    }

    public void setProductimage(String productimage) {
        this.productimage = productimage;
    }

    public String getResid() {
        return resid;
    }

    public void setResid(String resid) {
        this.resid = resid;
    }

    public String getSmallsizeprice() {
        return smallsizeprice;
    }

    public void setSmallsizeprice(String smallsizeprice) {
        this.smallsizeprice = smallsizeprice;
    }
}
```

**FoodsFromCatAdapter.java** (Adapter Class)

```
public class FoodsFromCatAdapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView i1cat;
    public TextView inamecat, ifromRescat, ihalforfullcat, iorpricecat, iratingscat;
    public Button gotores;

    public FoodsFromCatAdapter(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        i1cat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagecat);
        inamecat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemnamecat);
        ifromRescat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fromrescat);
        ihalforfullcat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemhalforfullcat);
        iorpricecat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.finalpricecat);
        gotores = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gotorescat);
        iratingscat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratecat);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Please check this code. I have looped through all the documents id's (that is the Restaurant ids) and add them to a list. Now I am using a for loop of strings to get the data from MenuItems. Please check it.
**This is in the Activity class**

```
collectionReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot:task.getResult()){
                    ResModel resModel = queryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(ResModel.class);
                    list.add(resModel.getResUserName());
                }

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for( String items : list){
                            Query query = collectionReference.document(items).collection("MenuItems").whereEqualTo("itemcat", catnameref);
                            menuModelFirestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<MenuModel>().setQuery(query, MenuModel.class).build();
                            adapterFirestoreRecyclerAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<MenuModel, FoodsFromCatAdapter>(menuModelFirestoreRecyclerOptions) {
                                @Override
                                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodsFromCatAdapter holder, int position, @NonNull MenuModel model) {
                                    holder.ifromRescat.setText(model.getResname());
                                    holder.inamecat.setText(model.getItemname());

                                }

                                @NonNull
                                @Override
                                public FoodsFromCatAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_product_item_from_cats, parent, false);
                                    return  new FoodsFromCatAdapter(view);
                                }
                            };
                            adapterFirestoreRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
                            itemrecycler.setAdapter(adapterFirestoreRecyclerAdapter);
                        }
                    }
                },2000 );



            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello Subham, Welcome to StackOverflow! :)
Could you clarify the phrase "but did not get the result"?

Comment: I want to get the particular menu items in the next activity by clicking the category item name.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect, when using collectionGroup()? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo  Query query = collectionReference.orderBy("MenuItems").whereEqualTo("itemCat", catnameref);

Comment: How is `collectionReference` defined?

Comment: @AlexMamo  collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurants");

Comment: @AlexMamo please follow the screenshots for proper db structure images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you are trying to order documents according to a property that doesn't exist. "MenuItems" is actually a sub-collection and not a property so you can perform an order:

```
collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurants");
Query query = collectionReference.orderBy("MenuItems").whereEqualTo("itemCat", catnameref);
```

To get all the all orders that correspond to a single user, please use the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference menuItemsRef = rootRef.collection("Restaurants").document("testuser1").collection("MenuItems");
Query queryByItemCat = menuItemsRef.whereEqualTo("itemCat", catnameref);
```

That's the Query that you should pass to the "setQuery()" method. If you need a specific order, then you can also add an `.orderBy("someProperty")` call, a case in which [an index is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working).

However, if want to get all orders of all users, a collection group Query is required:

```
rootRef.collectionGroup("MenuItems").whereEqualTo("itemCat", catnameref);
```

This means that this Query will get all documents that exist in each "MenuItems" collection of each user.

Comment: ok, I understand your statement, but i don't want to get items from specific doc id, like CollectionReference menuItemsRef = rootRef.collection("Restaurants").document("testuser1").collection("MenuItems");

Comment: i need to loop through all the document ids and then from there I need to collect the menuitems which has the same category names from the Sub-Collection "MenuItems"

Comment: If you don't want to get only the orders of a single user, then the single option that you have is the collection group query. Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847) might also help.

Comment: Hey, @Alex Mamo please check the update on this question.

Comment: When you encounter new problems, it's best to create a new question with everything you have done, and not update it. I'm this way, I and **other** developers, can take a look and try to help.

Comment: Ok, I will surely do that. But could you please check the update once?

Answer (score 0):

I have only done this in Flutter, but it looks like you need to actually use a collection group.
Your query should be something like this:

```
Query query = firebaseFirestore.collectionGroup("MenuItems").whereEqualTo("itemCat", catnameref);
```

Bear in mind that you will also need to create the corresponding index.  See the docs here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Comment: In this query you have directly calling collection group from Firestore object. And "Menuitems" is  under Restaurants collection so, didn't I have to use the Restaurants collection?

Comment: please reply the above question