# HOW TO ACCES ALL DOCUMENT FROM SUBCOLLECTION OF ALL DOCUMENT IN PYTHON

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

SUPPOSE I HAVE THIS FIRESTORE DATABASE:

collection > document_1 > user > doc1 > field1: value1
field2: value2
///////////> document_2 > user > doc2 > field3: value3

Comment: Please note that all-caps is often perceived as yelling, which might explain the number of downvotes you attracted.

Comment: The question should exist within the the body of text in your post (not in just the title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your post correctly you want to access a specific subcollection of all documents. If so, you are looking for a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which reads documents from all collections with a specific name.

Accessing that in Python is (according to the documentation linked above) done with:

```
museums = db.collection_group(u'landmarks')\
    .where(u'type', u'==', u'museum')
docs = museums.stream()
for doc in docs:
    print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

So this would query across all documents in collections named `u'landmarks`, no matter where in the database those collections exist.

Comment: I want to acces every document inside the subcollection user for all document inside the collection collection

Comment: That's possible too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847