# WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3 CollectionGroup is not a function - firebase collection group querying nested data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Prompt:
There are 5 products. Each product has 5 video reviews. These reviews are nested in the following data structure.

products > docs > productReviewClips > docs {videoUrl: https://videoclip.mp4, uid: 1234}.

Each productReviewClips doc has a videoUrl.

Am I querying the videoUrls from all the products the wrong way?

```
const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => { 
        firestore.collection('products').doc().collectionGroup('productReviewClips')
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot) + "1")

            setFeed([...snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                return {
                    ...doc.data(),
                    documentID: doc.id,
                };
            })
        ])

        })
        },
   [])
```

Comment: There's no need for `setFeed([...snapshot.docs.map((doc) => { /* ... */ })]);` as a new array is already generated by `map()`, just use `setFeed(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => { /* ... */ }));` instead. Otherwise, you are effectively doing `setFeed(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => { /* ... */ }).map(docData => docData));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `doc()` without arguments, it generates a new unique ID. For a collection group query, skip the initial `collection('products').doc()` altogether and do:

```
firestore.collectionGroup('productReviewClips')...
```

The [`collectionGroup`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Firestore#collectiongroup) function is a part of the `Firestore` object, it's not available on a `CollectionReference` or `DocumentReference` object which is also why you get the "not a function" error.

If you want to search only `productReviewClips` collections under a specific path, that is possible with a trick Sam explains here: [CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847)

Comment: Thank you both. I get now --Group is not part of Col or Doc. Really appreciate it, not all heroes wear physical capes, and will archive this for future reference.