# Firestore: Query multiple nested collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a nested collection in firestore as shown below:

```
db-dev
        user
             user-id-1
                       events-collection
                       ...
             user-id-2
                       events-collection
                       ...
             user-id-3
                       events-collection
                       ...
```

I want to query all the events from events-collection. However, I also want to keep the above schema as the admin needs to view all events-collection and specific users need to view their specific collection.

The query I write now looks something like this:

```
const uids = await getAllUserIds(); //Returns all user ID
const promises = uids.map(element => db.collection(`db-dev/user/${element}/events-collection/`).get())

const documents = await Promise.all(promises);
```

I am not very confident if this is the most optimized way to query the data or should I use something else? Can somebody please help me out here?

Comment: If you are interested, you can also check the following article, [How to query collections in Firestore under a certain path?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-query-collections-in-firestore-under-a-certain-path-6a0d686cebd2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To read from all `events-collection` collections in one go, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

For example, without any conditions, this reads all documents from all collections named `events-collection`:

```
db.collectionGroup('events-collection').get()
```

---

If you want to read only the `events-collection` collections under `/user`, you can use the trick that Sam showed here: [CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for quick response but the user-ids are dynamic won't that affect this?