# Unable to use firebase documentId() in node js admin sdk (firebase-admin npm package grammar issue)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My database looks like:

```
db-dev
   user-metadata
       portfolios
            meta
               pending
                       userId
                              events-collection
                                           doc1
                                           doc2
                                           ...
                       userId2
                              events-collection
                                           doc1
                                           doc2
                                           ...
               verified
                       userId
                              events-collection
                                           doc1
                                           doc2
                                           ...
                       userId2
                              events-collection
                                           doc1
                                           doc2
                                           ...
```

I want to fetch all docs that belong to verified events-collection. Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847) and this [Blog Post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-query-collections-in-firestore-under-a-certain-path-6a0d686cebd2) I tried to do the following:

```
export const getVerifiedEvents = async (eventType: DocumentType) => {
  //eventType is either pending or verified
  const rootRef = Server.db.collection(
    `${constDocumentRefs.merchants_meta_loc}/${eventType}`
  );

  const documents = await const documents = await Server.db
    .collectionGroup('events-collection')
    .orderBy(documentId())
    .startAt(rootRef.path)
    .endAt(rootRef.path + '\uf8ff')
    .get();
  return documents.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
};
```

But the above code throws me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'documentId')
  13 |   const documents = await Server.db
  14 |     .collectionGroup('events-collection')
> 15 |     .orderBy(firestore.documentId())
     |             ^
  16 |     .startAt(rootRef.path)
  17 |     .endAt(rootRef.path + '\uf8ff')
  18 |     .get();
```

Here's how my Server instance looks like:

```
import { auth, db, storage } from './firebase_server';

const firebaseServer = {
  auth,
  db,
  storage,
};

export default firebaseServer;
```

Where auth,db and storage are imported from following files:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

const keyString = process.env.FB_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY ?? '{"privateKey": ""}';

const { privateKey } = JSON.parse(keyString);

if (privateKey === '') {
  console.log('FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY is not set');
}

if (admin.apps.length === 0)
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
      clientEmail: process.env.FB_ADMIN_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: privateKey,
      projectId: process.env.FB_ADMIN_PROJECT_ID,
    }),
  });

const db = admin.firestore();
const auth = admin.auth();
const storage = admin.storage();

export { auth, db, storage };
```

To be precise, I am using `firebase-admin` ["firebase-admin": "^10.0.1"] npm package and this is just not working whereas in lots of places they have been directly using documentId() with ease. What's the correct grammar for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term `"undefined"` refers to a variable that has been declared but not given a value.
Only objects can have properties and functions in JavaScript. Because undefined is not an object type, executing a method or setting a property on it results in a TypeError: Undefined property cannot be read.

The path could be a single field name (pointing to a document's top level field) or a list of field names (referring to a nested field in the document).

The internal variable **id** in JavaScript just returns **id**.
Example: `.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())`

The example that is in the [blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-query-collections-in-firestore-under-a-certain-path-6a0d686cebd2) you are following is presented like:

`.orderBy(FieldPath.documentId())`

Comment: And where do you get `FIeldPath` in second case?

Comment: The FieldPath is explained in the blog next to point 2:
‘Since we know that there are some limitations when it comes to how much data we store in a single document, according to the official documentation regarding usage and limits’.

The shared documentation for usage and limitations also includes information on [Collections, documents, and fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields): 
‘May be passed as a string when all field names in the path are simple, otherwise must be passed as a FieldPath object (e.g. JavaScript FieldPath)’.

Comment: Please let me know if this comment answers your last comment.