# Searching within collection collectionGroup query

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So I came across this answer which allows limiting the collectionGroup query to a specific document: [CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847)

However I also want to further filter results based on a specific field using `where`, which required an index. The query works without errors but it always returns empty snapshot:

```
const cityRef = firebase.firestore().doc('cities/cityId');

firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('attractions')
  .where('name', '>=', keywords),
  .where('name', '<=', keywords + '\uf8ff')
  .orderBy('name')
  .orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
  .startAt(cityRef.path),
  .endAt(cityRef.path + "\uf8ff")
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    console.log("Found " + querySnapshot.size + " docs");
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => console.log("> " + doc.ref.path))
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to execute query", err);
  })
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of sample document ?

Comment: Can you *start* the query with the condition on the field path, and thus also order on that field first?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry how do you mean? Move `startAt` and `endAt` before `where`?  Tried that and still 0 docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The problem is almost certainly that your query has range checks on two different fields (`name` and the document path), which isn't possible in Firestore's query model. As the documentation on [query limitations says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

*Your `startAt` and `endAt` clauses are just different ways of writing `>` and `<` as far as this limitation is concerned.*

To understand why the SDK allow you to write this query, but doesn't give you the result you want, we'll have to dive a bit deeper into it, so...

---

What **is** possible, is to pass all relevant fields to `startAt` and `endAt` so that it can determine the correct slice across all those field values.

Doing that would also remove the need to even have the `where`, so it'd be:

```
firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('attractions')
  .orderBy('name')
  .orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
  .startAt(keywords, cityRef.path),
  .endAt(keywords + '\uf8ff', cityRef.path + "\uf8ff")
  .get()
  ...
```

But this query now first looks for the documents starting at `keywords` and then if necessary for `cityRef.path` in there to disambiguate between multiple results.

What you want is the equivalent of this query:

```
const docId = firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()l
firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('attractions')
  .orderBy('name')
  .where('name', '>=', keywords),
  .where('name', '<=', keywords + '\uf8ff')
  .orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
  .where(docId, '>=', cityRef.path),
  .where(docId, '<=', cityRef.path + '\uf8ff')
```

Now it's immediately clear why this isn't possible, because we have range conditions on two fields.

I've been trying to get that working in this jsbin (https://jsbin.com/yiyifin/edit?js,console), so far without success, but I'll post back if I get it working or have a final verdict on why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, bummer! So there's no way to restrict collectionGroup query to a specific collection/document and also range checks at the same time?

Comment: Hey @eozzy: after much more back and forth and testing, it indeed seems my original conclusion on why this doesn't work is correct. I edited my answer to clarify why it isn't possible in Firestore's query model at the moment.

Comment: Ah thanks for that. I ended up saving the keywords in an array and using array-contains-any working reasonably ok for now.