# get all document from 2 collection firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how to retrieve data from all documents in the first collection with a clause in the second collection.
I use this code but the data doesn't show up at all.. please help me..

```
dbf.collection("group").document().collection("member")
.whereEqualto("iduser", "098332")
                .orderBy("updatetime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list = value.getDocuments();

                    datalist.clear();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
                        final Modelfirestore c = d.toObject(Modelfirestore.class);
                        datalist.add(c);
                    

                    }
                    mAdapterss.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

I've tried with the script above but it doesn't work

Comment: If you don't have a direct question about Java avoid putting the Java tag. This will make your question more specific.

Comment: @SC291 This question is about code in Java, and the `[java]` tag is appropriate.

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly didn't work? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `document()` without an argument, it generates a references to a new, unique, non-existing document in your database. So you're querying a non-existing subcollection, which explains why you don't get any results.

---

If you want to query the `member` subcollection of a specific `group` document, specify the ID of that group document in the call to `document(...)`.

---

If you want to query across all `member` subcollections, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

---

If you want to query all `member` collections under `groups`, you can use a collection group query with the trick in Sam's answer here: [CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum)