# how to search collection within collection Cloud Firestore flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

how to search collection within collection firebase flutter?

how to search the collection within the collection firebase flutter?

Example

```
collection ="listOfDoctors" 

 document="sdfdfseewew"this id

collection="hospital"

document="sssfasf" this id

Fields

{

'':'',

'specialties':'h1',

'':'',

...

}
```

[image]

How do I search in specialties??

How do I get over iddocument  the first??

```
  getData() async {

    final listOfDoctors = await FirebaseFirestore.instance

        .collection('listOfDoctors')

        .where('specialties', arrayContainsAny: ['h1'])

        .get();

    print(listOfDoctors.size);

  }
```

Comment: `specialties` field is in `listOfDoctors` collection?

Comment: specialties field is in listOfDoctors/id/hospital/id collection

Comment: What you're looking for is [CollectionGroup Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search across all `hospital` collections in the entire database, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

If you want to search all `hospital` collections under a given path, have a look at the answer from samthecodingman here: [CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum)