# Firestore subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection inside a firestore called "movies" and there's movies info. Inside them there are subcollections. How can I retrieve those subcollections containing episodes of my movies. There's no docs in Firestore. Thanks

Comment: You can read this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) which explains several approaches to list sub-collections of a Document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a reference to the movies collection.
Something like this (assuming you have access to your Firestore database):

```
const moviesRef = collection(db, "movies");
```

Then make a document reference to a document inside the movies collection. You can use the `doc()` function which takes in the db reference, the collection, and the target document id. If you don't have the document id you can use `getDocs` to see all document ids in your collection. Finally once you have this document reference you can make a call to the sub collection which may look something like this:

```
const subcol = collection(<document reference>, "subcollection name");
```

From here you may use any way you need.

For more info check Firebase docs

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by [FieldPath.documentId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#documentid). It can return a special sentinel `FieldPath` to refer to the ID of a document. It can be used in queries to sort or filter by the document ID. You may check this posted answer [CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847).