# Flutter Firebase Multiple Document Id StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I have a document id list in my code, I want to use this id list in my new query. How can I enter multiple document id's?

```
StreamBuilder(
     stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Dersler")
     .document(dersler).collection("Kategori")
     .document(kategori).collection("Test")
     .snapshots(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {}
```

The "`dersler`" string contains: DRk5uDVZwITKqYVLPGP0, E0y2PMnoM8H9WTeObSzi, bpaBAs15EuEMRAUihVC2, g31ZgqRtmIaYVxyTNvqG

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to pass multiple IDs to the `document` call in your code. The closest you can get is by performing a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) on a path as samthecodingmanb shows in this answer: [CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847)

So you'd have an `in` condition on `firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()` with the document **path** prefixes for the documents you want to get. But even then you would not be able to include the `Kategori` in the path, and can only do this for up to 10 documents paths (the limit on an `in` condition).

---

If you can't get this approach to work (as I expect), your only alternative would be to perform a separate read for each document ID and merge the results in your application code.