# Firebase: How to fetch all documents in all collections under a single document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following test data where a single `test-course` has three units which each has multiple subunits.

[image]

I am able to retrieve all subunits in one unit at a time using `react-firebase-hooks` like below:

```
const [units, loading, error] = useCollection(
    session && query(collection(db, "courses", "test-course", "unit-1"))
  );
```

However, is there a way to fetch all units & subunits under a test-course? My goal is to render all of those units and subunits like this screenshot.

Or is there a better way to structure this data? Previous methods I thought of were:

- putting all subunit objects in one collection; but this seemed unintuitive as I need to track data/progress for each unit independently from one another

[image]

Comment: If you want to load the documents from all units under a given question, you can use the approach samthecodingman showed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention "under a single document" in the question title, I make the assumption that you want to display the data for one course at the time (`test-course` in your example). If this is correct you have two options:

##### Option 1: Execute X queries (X = 3 in your example)

You execute a query for each `unit` Document and you merge the results in the front end

##### Option 2: Denormalize data (i.e. duplicate data)

You put all subunit Documents in one collection, as you mentioned, and you add the parent unit value **as a field** in each subunit document. This way you can sort the subunit documents per unit and display them under the correct unit category.

You can also execute a query that filters the collection based on the unit value, in order to the subunits of one unit (or several units with the [`in`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=en&authuser=0#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) operator)