# Firestore query subcollections based on the parent collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have the following structure in Firestore using sub collections:

Organization(parent)

- Equipment(sub)
- News(sub)

I have an array of references to the organizations. I want to have all news items in the subcollection News where the organization is in the array.

How can I achieve this without starting a listener for each organization. Can anyone give a query example.

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to perform a query on the parent path, as sam explains here: [CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847). But you'll likely still need multiple such queries.

To prevent that, the only option is to include the necessary information that you want to query on (so the organization ID) in each News document, and then [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) with an `in` condition to filter on tht.