# How to count total similar subcollections across multiple documents in Firestore

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore user database structured with each person's data stored under their own document (instead of relating to top-level collections like in traditional RDBMS). Now I would like to count global figures across all users, and it seems I would have to iterate over the users and count each subcollection, then add up the total manually. Is there some document wildcard I can use to perform this in one query e.g. in the query builder?

e.g. the structure is like this, where all user document share a common structure but with different collection lengths depending on user activity:

```
/users/USERID1/sessions/
    - SESSION1/
    - SESSION2/
/users/USERID2/sessions/
    - SESSION1/
/users/USERID3/sessions/
    - SESSION1/
    - SESSION2/
    - SESSION3/
    - SESSION4/
/users/USERID4/sessions/
    - SESSION1/
    - SESSION1/
    - SESSION2/
```

I know I can use the newish count() function to do something like `collection('/users/USERID1/sessions/').count().get()` but then I'd have to run this for USERID1, USERID2, USERID3 etc.

So is there a way to do a cross-section aggregate of all user documents like '/users/*/sessions/'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this can be done via Collection Groups

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

e.g.
`const querySnapshot = await db.collectionGroup('landmarks').where('type', '==', 'museum').get();`

So I should be able to do

```
const count = await db.collectionGroup('session').count().get();
```

and further, count different types of sessions

```
const count = await db.collectionGroup('session').where('type', '==', 'web').count().get();
```

This is also supported in the query builder in the Firebase control panel, under the "query scope" dropdown, which appears to have a list of all collections across my database.

My only worry here is that it presumably includes all "sessions" collections from any document in the entire database, not just "user/*/sessions". I don't think I have any others named that way but in general this could be a trap for other more generically named collections which might appear in different document contexts.

Comment: If you want to query by path, see the answer from sam here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847