# Firestore native mode 'collection group' query limited by a common ancestor

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

is there a way to limit 'collection group' queries in firestore native, such that only records from a given ancestor path are returned?

consider the following collection structure:

**cafe**

-cafeA

---reviews

---menu-items

-cafeB

---reviews

---menu-items

**restaurants**

-restaurantA

---reviews

---menu-items

-restaurantB

---reviews

---menu-items

if i query on collection group 'menu-items' then i get **all** the menu items for **both** cafes and restaurants

can i use a where clause with ancestor path or wildcard, to limit the query scope to only those documents within, say the 'cafe' ancestor collection?

Comment: It's not really a documented feature, but @samthecodingman found a way to do so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-query-collections-in-firestore-under-a-certain-path-6a0d686cebd2) will also help.

Comment: brilliant!  got it working now!  as i understand this query will still scale with the size of the results set because startAt will skip a large portion of the index, right?