# Trying to pass the last document snapshot back to client from a Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am running a query from a Firebase Cloud Function and I want to return the last snapshot so I can then use it for pagination. I get the last snapshot in the logger, however, I get the below error:

> Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Heres the code:

```
function lastSnapshot(querySnapshot) {
  return querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
}

const [sponsored, timed, popular, all] = await Promise.all([
  sponsoredQuery.get(),
  timedQuery.get(),
  popularQuery.get(),
  allQuery.get(),
]);

const lastVenue = lastSnapshot(all);

return {
  sections: processedResults,
  lastVenue: lastVenue,
};
```

My code works perfectly fine without passing the lastVenue back.

### Query code:

```
const venueBaseRef = firestore
  .collection("venues")
  .where("city_id", "==", city)
  .where("active", "==", true);

const allQuery = venueBaseRef.orderBy("updated_at", "desc").limit(15);
```

### Snapshot Log:

```
QueryDocumentSnapshot {
  _fieldsProto: {
    ...SNAPSHOT FIELDS
  },
  _ref: DocumentReference {
    _firestore: Firestore {
      _settings: [Object],
      _settingsFrozen: true,
      _serializer: [Serializer],
      _projectId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      _databaseId: '(default)',
      registeredListenersCount: 0,
      bulkWritersCount: 0,
      _backoffSettings: [Object],
      _clientPool: [ClientPool],
      _gax: [Object]
    },
    _path: QualifiedResourcePath {
      segments: [Array],
      projectId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      databaseId: '(default)'
    },
    _converter: {
      toFirestore: [Function: toFirestore],
      fromFirestore: [Function: fromFirestore]
    }
  },
  _serializer: Serializer {
    createReference: [Function (anonymous)],
    createInteger: [Function (anonymous)],
    allowUndefined: false
  },
  _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1703684076, _nanoseconds: 567040000 },
  _createTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1702043723, _nanoseconds: 945695000 },
  _updateTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1703683586, _nanoseconds: 824383000 }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to know what the problem is. Please edit the question to show the complete minimal function code that has a problem, and also share the data you're working with so we know what's in all the variables.  Hard code as much data as you can to be clear.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added my query and the last snapshot value from the logger.

Comment: That doesn't look like the complete code for a Cloud Function that anyone could copy and run for themselves to duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

When using query pagination, you don't need an actual `DocumentSnapshot` instance. You can pass [an array of fields used for sorting](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#startAfter) in its place.

Based on the provided query, you have two `orderBy` clauses on `allQuery` (merged for the sake of clarity):

```
const allQuery = firestore
  .collection("venues")
  .where("city_id", "==", city)
  .where("active", "==", true)
  .orderBy("updated_at", "desc")
  .orderBy(documentId(), "asc") // hidden, added at the end when not explicitly provided by developer
  .limit(15);
```

This means that you only need the following statement to paginate it.

```
// assuming lastVenue is not undefined (which occurs when no documents matched query)
const nextPageSnapshot = await allQuery
  .startAfter(lastVenue.get("updated_at"), lastVenue.id)
  .get();
```

In your case, you would return these arguments from your function:

```
return {
  sections: processedResults,
  lastVenueOrderByFields: lastVenue
    ? [lastVenue.get("updated_at"), lastVenue.id]
    : null;
}
```

While you could return `{ _id: lastVenue.id, ...lastVenue.data() }` above, this would then mean that your functions code would either rely on your client-side code to provide each argument or the whole data object with the next request. A client should simply send the returned value back to the server as-is and here we provide the smallest amount of data needed.

Now that we have the `orderBy` fields, we can use them in the next query once extracted from the next request (specifics depend on the type of Cloud Function used):

```
const { lastVenueOrderByFields } = /* request data object */;

// ...

let pagedAllQuery = allQuery;

// add orderBy clause when needed
if (lastVenueOrderByFields != null) {
  // validate!
  if (!Array.isArray(lastVenueOrderByFields) || lastVenueOrderByFields.length == 0) {
    throw new Error("Invalid lastVenueOrderByFields value provided"); // use HttpsError as needed
  }

  pagedAllQuery = allQuery
    .startAfter(...lastVenueOrderByFields);
}

const pageResultsQuerySnapshot = await pagedAllQuery.get();
```

Comment: just to confirm from what I understood in your answer, Firestore automatically adds to the order (as the last param) "orderBy" documentID? unless explicitly set otherwise.

Comment: @DavidHenry `documentId()` returns `__name__` and is the document's ID for regular queries. Sorting by ID last allows for [consistent ordering of documents when paginating your query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data). Your query would have an order of `updated_at desc, __name__ asc`. However, if you wanted to sort by the ID first by calling `someQuery.orderBy(documentId(), "asc").orderBy("updated_at", "desc")`, the implicit `__name__ asc` is no longer added at the end because the order would be `__name__ asc, updated_at desc` already.

Comment: FYI: For collection group queries, the `__name__` field is the path of the document instead of just its document ID. This is because two different documents may share the same ID but be located in different collections. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049847/3068190) for details on why that is useful.